# A Calm Before The Storm

Tags: riddle, rhyme, acrostic

Since my last couple riddles were in the difficult realm, I figured I would write some simpler riddles for a while. This one is inspired by my new project at home (which ironically is proving more difficult to perfect than I expected). Can you guess what I am building?

> No flowers, nor shrubs, straight edges, round curves;
>
> Everything peaceful, no noise to be heard.
>
> Zeal for this place, mine like no other; perfect, I think, ideal for a mother.

**Note**: If you leave a down-vote, please explain how I can improve the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you building a

> ZEN GARDEN?

No flowers, nor shrubs, straight edges, round curves;

> These are all characteristics of a zen garden.

Everything peaceful, no noise to be heard.

> Definitely in the spirit of zen.

Zeal for this place, mine like no other; perfect, I think, ideal for a mother.

> You get to create your own and maintain it.

The acrostic tag is because

> The first letters are NEZ, which is ZEN backwards.

Comment: Ahh, reverse acrostic nice

Comment: I thought it was bed too @Joe-You-Know, until I realized that nobody starts sentences with Z outside of this website ;P

Comment: It's funny you mention not starting sentences with Z; in my opinion, it's one of the most difficult letters to start a sentence with. Unless, perhaps you're starting with X, which is a difficult letter as well (unless you're talking about Xylophones). :D

Comment: Outside of maybe a presentation on Zebras, or talking to my friend Zach, I don't think I've started that many sentences with Z haha :D X would be bad too!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure on this one but it might be a:

> Garden pond. The title itself sounds a bit sea-like

No flowers, nor shrubs, straight edges, round curves;

> Like a garden pond - round shape, straight edges.

Everything peaceful, no noise to be heard.

Zeal for this place, mine like no other; perfect, I think, ideal for a mother.

Comment: Good guess, but no; someday I would like to build one of those rot13(fjvzzvat cbaqf) though!

Answer (score 2):

Is it a

> Bed?

No flowers, nor shrubs, straight edges, round curves;

> Beds have round curves, but are rectangles.

Everything peaceful, no noise to be heard.

> Sleep is peaceful.

Zeal for this place, mine like no other; perfect, I think, ideal for a mother.

> A bed is perfect for a mother, for them to sleep. Your zealous about it, because it is how you rest.

Comment: This was a great answer Joe! That would be a fascinating build as I would have to go with an older style; perhaps Nordic or Victorian. +1

Comment: If I want peace or quiet, it's where I go :-)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love that particular place!